# Middle Character swift

Tags: swift

I have an issue I am trying to solve

I am trying to find middle character of the word. If the word's length is odd, return the middle character. If the word's length is even, return the middle 2 characters

```
func middle(_ str: String) -> String {
    let arr = Array(str).map{$0}

    print(arr)
//    if arr.count
    for myInt: String in arr {
        if myInt % 2 == 0 {
            println("\(myInt) is even number")
        } else {
            println("\(myInt) is odd number")
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your string is the whole word (otherwise you would need to enumerate your string byWords before using this property):

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var middle: SubSequence {
        if isEmpty { return "" }
        if count == 1 { return  self[startIndex...startIndex] }
        let middleIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: count/2)
        let previous = index(before: middleIndex)
        return count % 2 == 0 ? self[previous...middleIndex] : self[middleIndex...middleIndex]
    }
}
```

---

```
"abc".middle
"abcd".middle
```

Comment: cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Self.SubSequence'

Comment: Show your context. If you need a String instead of Substring just initialize a new String with it

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function:

```
func middle(_ str: String) -> String {

    let count = str.count

    if count < 2 {
        return str
    }

    let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: (count - 1)/2)
    let end = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: (count + 2)/2)

    return String(str[start..<end])
}
```

Here are some use cases:

```
middle("")          //""
middle("1")         //"1"
middle("12")        //"12"
middle("123")       //"2"
middle("1234")      //"23"
middle("12345")     //"3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to approach this systematically. The first task would be to determine the offsets of the first and last character of the “middle part”. If we make a table with some representative cases

```
string  result  length  first   last
------------------------------------
a       a       1       0       0
ab      ab      2       0       1
abc     b       3       1       1
abcd    bc      4       1       2
abcde   c       5       2       2
abcdef  cd      6       2       3
```

then we can derive that

```
firstIndex = (length - 1) / 2
lastIndex = length / 2
```

where `/` is the *truncating* integer division. An empty string has to be treated separately.

Finally we need to know how to work with indices and offsets in a Swift string, which is explained in [A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md).

This leads to the implementation

```
func middle(_ str: String) -> String {
    if str.isEmpty { return "" }
    let len = str.count
    let fromIdx = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: (len - 1)/2)
    let toIdx = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: len/2)
    return String(str[fromIdx...toIdx])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one more example:

add this extension

```
extension StringProtocol {

    subscript(offset: Int) -> Element {
        return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
    }
    subscript(range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        return prefix(range.lowerBound + range.count)
            .suffix(range.count)
    }
}
```

use this like

```
let stringLength: Int = str.count
if stringLength % 2 == 0{
    //even
    print(str[((stringLength/2) - 1)...(stringLength/2)])
}else{
    //odd
    print(str[(stringLength/2) - 1])
}
```